# Using Regex in VS Find to find non commented out lines

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am totally new to regex's and as such am failing. I have about 14000 lines that reference a function which needs to be commented out. Not a problem. Im just tired of seeing the same lines in my find results that have already been taken care of... basically I am trying this:

```
  ({^?!'}Green.Foo*)
```

which is still returning all commented out results...

Answer (score 0):

You want a zero-width negative look**behind**, so something like this should do `(?<!')Green.Foo*` Take a look at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx) under Grouping Constructs.

I'm assuming your code is in VB of course.

Comment: I did actually look over that and that is where I started at.. Im getting 0 matching lines and if I search without regex just Green.Foo it returns 13944 lines in 356 files. But the results include the 'Green.Foo lines